# Characters counting only in one textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have many inputs and one textarea in my page. I want to count the characters from all 
these inputs/textarea.

HTML:

```
<textarea name="texto_envio" class="form-control txtArea" maxlength="160"></textarea>
<input type="text"maxlength=3" class="form-control txtArea" />
<input type="text"maxlength=3" class="form-control txtArea" />
<span class="caracteres">160</span> restantes<br>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("input keyup", ".txtArea", function () {
    var limite = 160;
    var caracteresDigitados = $(this).val().length;
    var caracteresRestantes = limite - caracteresDigitados;
    $(".caracteres").text(caracteresRestantes);
});
```

Like...if I write "abc" in textarea and if I also write "abc" in both inputs, it will show "151 restantes".

I tried this code above but it only count the element that I am writing in. I write "abc" in textarea then span shows me "157 restantes". With "abc" written in textarea, I also write "abc" in one of the inputs. But the span shows me "157 restantes".

Span is reseting when I write in the other element.

What can I do to make it count every element (textarea and inputs)?

Comment: Use `each` to iterate over all elements having `.txtArea` class and make the total of all characters. [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/7apsc3v2/)

Comment: How can I use each? I am a begginer on jquery.

Comment: Sorry, as I am doing in a php file, I just put the tag. But I will remove the tag. My bad.

Comment: Thanks for the support @mickmackusa. I already marked the code that worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate all characters in `.txtArea` with `.each` function:

```js
$('.txtArea').on("keyup", function() {
  var limite = 160;
  $('.txtArea').each(function() {
    limite -= $(this).val().length
    $(".caracteres").text(limite);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="texto_envio" class="form-control txtArea" maxlength="160"></textarea>
<input type="text" maxlength=3 " class="form-control txtArea " />
<input type="text "maxlength=3" class="form-control txtArea" />
<span class="caracteres">160</span> restantes<br>
```

Comment: Wise choice @LeonardoSantos . Using the subtraction assignment operator, IMO, is the best approach.  Good answer shozdeh +1 from me.  (good edit)  ...you may want to explain the `-=` syntax to future readers; it is what sets your answer apart from the others.

Answer (score 1):

The event method will attach event handler for each input separately. So `$(this).val().length` refers to the specific input that triggered the event.

In the event you'll have to call a method that reads from all inputs.

```js
$(document).on('keyup', 'textarea, input', countChars);

function countChars() {
  var total = 0;
  $('textarea, input').each(function(i, el) {
    total += el.value.length
  });
  var remaining = 160 - total;
  $('span').text(remaining + ' remaining');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<span></span>
```

Comment: Just tried copying some content, right click on text field, and clicked on paste. Content got pasted, but count didn't got updated.

Comment: @MilanChheda I only added keyup event in my example. If you want to support other events you can add them after keyup (separated by space). The example is not supposed to be a production ready solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution,
This will read all the elements with class *txtArea* and count the characters from each. in this way you will get the total character count.

```
<textarea name="texto_envio" class="form-control txtArea" maxlength="160"></textarea>
<input type="text" maxlength="3" class="form-control txtArea" />
<input type="text" maxlength="3" class="form-control txtArea" />
```

JS

```
$(document).on("input keyup", ".txtArea", function () {
var limit = 160;
   var count = 0;
   var inputElements = $(".txtArea").each(function(){
       count += $(this).val().length;
   });
 $(".caracteres").text(limit - count);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Count all char from all input/textarea fields.**

> HTML

```
<textarea name="texto_envio" 
class="form-control txtArea" maxlength="160"></textarea>
<input type="text" maxlength="3" class="form-control txtArea" />
<input type="text" maxlength="3" class="form-control txtArea" />
<span class="caracteres">160</span> restantes<br>
```

> Script

```
$('.txtArea').on("keyup",function () {
    var limite = 160;
    var caracteresDigitados =0;
    $('.txtArea').each(function(){
      caracteresDigitados += $(this).val().length;
    });
    $(".caracteres").text(limite - caracteresDigitados);
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanations somewhere in your answer for the benefit of the OP and future readers.  It may seem very simple to understand for some, but for others this may be difficult to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to loop through all input elements and use `length` to count the number of characters entered per input.

Secondly, I would recommend to use `input` event instead of `keyup` or `keydown` as that `input` takes care of everything (even copy-paste). Below is the updated snippet:

```js
$(document).on('input', 'textarea, input', countChar);

function countChar() {
  var len = 0;
  $('input,textarea').each(function() {
    var enteredValue = $(this).val();
    len += enteredValue.length;
    $('#charCount').text(len);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<span id='charCount'></span>
```